# httaccess 301 redirect without URL variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having a problem making a 301 redirection.

My old URL is

```
https://example.com/es/component/users/registration?item=21
```

The new one is

```
https://example.com/es/login/registro
```

So, I wrote this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^es\/component\/users\/registration\/?item=21$  "https://mywebsite.com/es/login/registro" [R=301,L]
```

But it redirects to `https://mywebsite.com/es/login/registro?item=21`

how can I get rid of this `?item=21` string too?

Answer (score 0):

The directive you posted wouldn't actually perform the redirect as stated, unless the `?` was URL encoded (as `%3F`) in the request and there is no actual query string? Or you are seeing a cached response from an earlier (erroneous) attempt? (301 redirects will be cached persistently by the browser.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. To match against the query string you need an additional `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=21$
RewriteRule ^es/component/users/registration$ /es/login/registro [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+) removes the query string from the redirect response. Otherwise, the default action is to append the query string from the request. If you are using Apache 2.2 then you will need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead (essentially appending an empty query string).

No need to backslash escape the slashes in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect before changing to a 301 (if that is the intention) when you are sure it's working OK in order to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.